# When using Libsass/Grunt is there a way to watch files on the fly?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation-5, libsass

I have installed Foundation 5 using

```
>gem install foundation
```

And then creating a new project using the command

```
>foundation scratch --libsass
```

The main reason being is that I'm on Windows and I really don't need/want to be using compass. I know that after I make changes to my sass files that I can run

```
>grunt build
```

In order to update my css files from the changes I made to my `.scss` files. And Everything works fine.

Question: Is there a way that I can watch these `.scss` files so that I don't have to run that command every time I save my files. Kind of like I use to do with `>compass watch`? There is a dev dependency in `package.json` called `grunt-contrib-watch` is that it? If so, How do I use it?

Here is the Gruntfile I have once the install was finished:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
      options: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'compressed',
          sourceMap: true,
        },
        files: {
          'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      grunt: {
        options: {
          reload: true
        },
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },

      sass: {
        files: 'scss/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build','watch']);
}
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: Why is this an SO question? You know the package (`grunt-contrib-watch`) just check the git page for tons of examples (including examples on how to watch SASS files) - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload

Comment: If you noticed I edited the question once I started to find the answer, so at the beginning I had no idea. And I did search google and Stack overflow for what I thought would have given me the answer and came up short. The question is valid and the answer is valid no matter how obvious it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did some sleuthing and looked into the grunt file and even though I'm not that great with grunt I saw this:

```
watch: {
    grunt: {
        options: {
            reload: true
        },
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
    },

    sass: {
        files: 'scss/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
    }
}
```

With this I assumed that I could just run:

```
>grunt watch
```

I know, I might not be the brightest tool in the shed, but I'm new and didn't realize that when I installed Foundation this way that it also installed this `grunt-contrib-watch` dependency. Sorry if this question is too obvious maybe it will help someone though because it was hard for me to find the answer even though it was in the package.json that I'm not use to using.

Comment: I'm not removing the answer or the question. I struggled with it and just because I'm a noob and didn't understand how things work does not mean someone else will not find it helpful, no matter how dumb they are (Like me). Downvote it all you want!

Comment: I don't know who down-voted you, but I have a suggestion - from reading your answer it's not actually clear what the *solution* to your original issue is. Perhaps if you edited to make it clearer, it would be more useful to others (incidentally, you did the right thing here by providing an answer, kudos and don't lose heart!)

Comment: Hi Stephen, I understand what you are saying. And it's the reason when I do post questions on SO that I actually define the question. After reading this one again I realize that I was a little vague. I'll see what I can do to make this question better reflect the issue and question I had. One thing to take into consideration is that I asked the question and while writing and posting for the first time realized that there was a `grunt-contrib-watch` dependency. So I included it in the question because I felt it was important, it was only after that that I realized and a posted an answer..

Comment: that's great, too many questions on SO get abandoned and it's nice to see someone taking an active interest in improving quality. Would uv again if I could :)